# @ManagedProperty equivalent in Spring

Tags: spring, jsf-2

I am using Spring for my DI.
Is there an equivalent of @ManagedProperty? I want to inject the value from one view scoped bean into another one on the next page.

e.g

```
@Component
@Scope("view")
public class Page1Bean(){
   private String value;
}

@Component
@Scope("view")
public class Page2Bean(){
    @ManagedProperty(value = #{page1Bean}")  //doesnt work in Spring
    private Page1Bean bean;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Resource` or `@Autowired` should work.  `@Resource` is the Java EE implementation, `@Autowired` is the spring specific annotation. I can't find the reference now, but it seems like I read once to prefer `@Resource` over `@Autowired`.

here's a blog post I found that talks about `@Inject` vs. `@Resource` vs. `@Autowired`
http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2011/08/spring-injection-with-resource-and-autowired/#more-2350

Comment: I believe this will instantiate a new Page1Bean..I want to pass along the actual Page1Bean with all its contents.

Comment: I've been using @Inject..I think thats JEE version.

Comment: for porting jsf view scope to spring: http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/port-jsf-2-0s-viewscope-to-spring-3-0/

Comment: It shouldn't create a new Page1Bean unless one doesn't exist in the given scope. Since you aren't using one of the known scopes from Spring that may be why you believe it will instantiate a new Page1Bean.

Comment: I've already ported view scope. View scope only exists on the current view. If you navigate to another page the bean will not be in scope and will be recreated. I've tested this using the post construct method.