# Problem with spring defined @ManagedProperty

Tags: spring, jsf, managed-bean, managed-property

I'm currently mantainning a Maven based JSF Web Application combined with Spring Framework and JPA and connected to a SQL Server database.

Inside the application, I created one `@ManagedBean` class defined with the  `@ViewScoped` and `@Scope("view")` annotations.

This class is named `AvisoRecaladaBean` and it has 3 attributes defined with the `@ManagedProperty` annotation as follows:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{jsf2Util}")
private Jsf2Util jsf2Util;

@ManagedProperty("#{avisoRecaladaService}")
private ISigcueCertAvisoRecaladaService avisoRecaladaService;

@ManagedProperty("#{usuarioService}")
private IUsuarioService usuarioService;
```

The first and third attributes were used in other managed beans in the same application. Also, `IUsuarioService` and `ISigcueAvisoRecaladaService` are interfaces, each one implemented by one class defined with the `@Service` annotation. The class that implements the latter interface also has the `@Transactional` annotation. `JsfUtil` is a class also defined with `@Service`.

Also, I defined one `Integer` attribute named `folioBusqueda` and one `List<SigcueCertAvisoRecalada>` attribute named `listado`. `SigcueCertAvisoRecalada` is an entity class pointing to a table in the database mencioned in the beginning.

Each attribute mentioned above has it's getter and setter.

In the other hand, I created one XHTML page named avisoRecalada.xhtml, that works with the `AvisoRecaladaBean` managed Bean.

The XHTML page has, among other things, one Panel Grid defined as follows:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">
    <label>Ingrese Número de Folio: *</label>
    <p:inputNumber placeholder="Folio del Aviso Recalada"
                   value="#{avisoRecaladaBean.folioBusqueda}"
                   required="true"
                   id="numeroFolio"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Obtener Certificado Aviso" 
                     actionListener="#{avisoRecaladaBean.buscarRegistro()}" 
                     update="idTablaAviso"/>
    <h:message for="numeroFolio" style="color:red"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

The `actionListener` inside the command button refeers to the following method in `AvisoRecaladaBean`

```
public void buscarRegistro() {
    SigcueCertAvisoRecalada item = avisoRecaladaService.findByFolio(folioBusqueda);
    listado.clear();
    if(item!=null) {
        listado.add(item);
    }
}
```

The Spring configuration is defined in an XML file defined as follows (I show only the important part):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:drools="http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbossrules/trunk/drools-container/drools-spring/src/main/resources/org/drools/container/spring/drools-spring-1.0.0.xsd
        http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd       
        ">      
    <context:component-scan base-package="cl.sernapesca" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Bean definitions -->

    <tx:annotation-driven/> 
    <tx:jta-transaction-manager />  

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:singleSingOn.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:revision.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:ldapExternos.properties</value> 
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>  

    <!-- View Scope para JSF2 -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
        <property name="scopes">
            <map>
               <entry key="view">
                       <bean class="cl.sernapesca.mantenedorcentral.arquitectura.ViewScope" />
               </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- More Bean definitions -->
</beans>
```

The faces-config.xml has only the following managed-beans defined:

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>currentDate</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>java.util.Date</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
 </managed-bean>
```

And it's resolver is defined as:

```
<application>
  <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
  <!-- More configurations -->
</application>
```

When I deploy the application using a WildFly 10 Application Server, I get no error messages. Also, I get no errors when I access the XHTML page.

However, when I input one value in the input text and push the command button, I get one `NullPointerException`. The stack trace indicates that the exception were launched when trying to execute the first line of `buscarRegistro()`.

After some debugging, I found that the `avisoRecaladaService` attribute was null, **but the other two managed properties weren't**.

I tried the following solutions with no avail

1. Add and/or replace `@ManagedProperty` with `@Autowired`
2. Use the `@Qualifier` annotation to name the bean (I named it `"avisoRecaladaService"`) and use the current `ApplicationContext` to get the bean (Source: [Spring Bean never set as ManagedProperty in JSF Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24530270/spring-bean-never-set-as-managedproperty-in-jsf-bean)). I got a `NoSuchBeanException` with this solution:

```
WebApplicationContext webAppContext = ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
avisoRecaladaService = (IAvisoRecaladaService) webAppContext.getBean("avisoRecaladaService");
```

3. **EDIT**: Instantiate avisoRecaladaService directly. **Not desirable. Also, autowired attributes of SigcueCertAvisoRecaladaService are null**:

```
public void buscarRegistro() {
        if(avisoRecaladaService==null)
            avisoRecaladaService=new SigcueCertAvisoRecaladaService();
        SigcueCertAvisoRecalada item = avisoRecaladaService.findByFolio(folioBusqueda);
        listado.clear();
        if(item!=null) {
            if(listado==null)
                listado=new ArrayList<>();
            listado.add(item);
        }
    }
```

4. **EDIT**: Replace `@ManagedAttribute` with `@Resource` (Source: [@ManagedProperty equivalent in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130140/managedproperty-equivalent-in-spring))
5. Replace `@ManagedAttribute` with `@Inject` (same source as the previous solution)

Any advice for a definitive solution would be really much obligated.

**EDIT**

As requested by Kukeltje, according to the application's pom.xml, the involved libraries are the following:

- jboss-jsf-api 2.2
- jboss-el-api 3.0 spec
- spring-core 4.2.8
- spring-web 4.2.8
- spring-expression 4.2.8
- spring-context-support 4.2.8
- spring-web-mvc 4.2.8
- JDK 1.8.0_191
- Developed in Eclipse Oxygen (if relevant)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your extensive description (a little too much even maybe) and pieces of code. Next time please also add version info (and implementation if relevant) of the libraries involved (you may edit the question). If '2' in your last bullit list is not working (should `modelOperations` be `avisoRecaladaService`?), it looks like it is not JSF related or EL resolver related or... Pure spring thing. And '1' only helps if the bean is made into a spring managed one and not a JSF managed one. And `@ViewScoped` and `@Scope("view")` on the same bean is not 'correct' (the latter is superfluous)

Comment: Yes, i replaced ```modelOperations``` a couple of minutes ago.

@ViewScoped and @Scope("view") are on all Managed Beans (i just copy them on my new class).

Like i said, the beans.xml file's component-scan tag covers all packages in the project.

Now i'm trying another solutions so it's more probably I have to edit the problem's description.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Thanks to a partner of mine, We discovered that `@ManagedProperty` is **very sensitive** about names. The name of the bean must be *exactly the same* as the class, with it's first letter in lower case. If the object is an interface instance, like in my case, it must be the name of the class implementing it.

So, I had to change this:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{avisoRecaladaService}")
private ISigcueCertAvisoRecaladaService avisoRecaladaService;
```

Into this:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{sigcueCertAvisoRecaladaService}")
private ISigcueCertAvisoRecaladaService sigcueCertAvisoRecaladaService;
```

Thanks to all of you for reading this and I hope this helps to similar problems in the future

Comment: Look to me this is not  about 'sensitivity' in names like `bla` vs 'Bla` but about not being able to 'inject' based on an interface.